# How to convert a dataframe to dataset in Apache Spark in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-encoders

I need to convert my dataframe to a dataset and I used the following code:

```
    val final_df = Dataframe.withColumn(
      "features",
      toVec4(
        // casting into Timestamp to parse the string, and then into Int
        $"time_stamp_0".cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType),
        $"count",
        $"sender_ip_1",
        $"receiver_ip_2"
      )
    ).withColumn("label", (Dataframe("count"))).select("features", "label")

    final_df.show()

    val trainingTest = final_df.randomSplit(Array(0.3, 0.7))
    val TrainingDF = trainingTest(0)
    val TestingDF=trainingTest(1)
    TrainingDF.show()
    TestingDF.show()

    ///lets create our liner regression
    val lir= new LinearRegression()
    .setRegParam(0.3)
    .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
    .setMaxIter(100)
    .setTol(1E-6)

    case class df_ds(features:Vector, label:Integer)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this)

    val Training_ds = TrainingDF.as[df_ds]
```

My problem is that, **I got the following error:**

```
Error:(96, 36) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val Training_ds = TrainingDF.as[df_ds]
```

It seems that the number of values in dataframe is different with the number of value in my class. However I am using `case class df_ds(features:Vector, label:Integer)` on my TrainingDF dataframe since, It has a vector of features and an integer label. Here is TrainingDF dataframe:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Also here is my original **final_df** dataframe:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
|time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.2|   10|
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

However I got the mentioned error! Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41):

The error message you are reading is a pretty good pointer.

When you convert a `DataFrame` to a `Dataset` you have to have a proper `Encoder` for whatever is stored in the `DataFrame` rows.

Encoders for primitive-like types (`Int`s, `String`s, and so on) and `case classes` are provided by just importing the implicits for your `SparkSession` like follows:

```
case class MyData(intField: Int, boolField: Boolean) // e.g.

val spark: SparkSession = ???
val df: DataFrame = ???

import spark.implicits._

val ds: Dataset[MyData] = df.as[MyData]
```

If that doesn't work either is because the type you are trying to *cast* the `DataFrame` to isn't supported. In that case, you would have to write your own `Encoder`: you may find more information about it [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Encoder.html) and see an example (the `Encoder` for `java.time.LocalDateTime`) [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-ExpressionEncoder-LocalDateTime.html).

Answer (score 6):

**Spark 1.6.0**

```
case class MyCase(id: Int, name: String)

val encoder = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[MyCase]

val dataframe = …

val dataset = dataframe.as(encoder)
```

**Spark 2.0 or above**

```
case class MyCase(id: Int, name: String)

val encoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[MyCase]

val dataframe = …

val dataset = dataframe.as(encoder)
```