# Is it possible to create a Dataset of Dataframes in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This might be a stupid question. But just out of curiosity, can I do the following

```
var rawDF = spark.read
        .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("header", "false")
        .csv(hdfs_file)

val trainRatio = 0.8
val testRatio = 0.2
val Array(trainDF, testDF) = rawDF.randomSplit(Array(trainRatio, testRatio))
var temp : Dataset[DataFrame] = spark.emptyDataset[DataFrame]
val sampleDataset = Seq(trainDF,testDF).toDS()
temp = temp.union(sampleDataset)
```

In Intellij, I am getting error at `.toDS()` line. Let's say if we could do this, then we could easily apply the map opeartion on Dataset to compute arbitary computation on the dataframes inside it. Am I wrong to think this? Does this have to do with encoders not being present for Dataframe?

Comment: Hi, Please refer this. we need to import implicits .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516627/how-to-convert-a-dataframe-to-dataset-in-apache-spark-in-scala/44516773

Comment: I have already imported implicits. So I guess it is not related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Dataframe and Dataset are both distributed collections and they are not serializable.

Answer (score 1):

As Vladislav earlier answered you cannot create a Dataset of Dataframes, **but you can** definately create a list of DataFrames (or Datasets or RDDs) if it makes sense !

For instance you can define a List of Dataframes, define the same transformations and concurrently run the same actions on each.

Comment: You mean using something like this : https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: For the concurrent aspect, you can use a standard collection, wrapping functional concurrent types like Task (https://monix.io/docs/3x/eval/task.html) or at least the -impure but famous- Future :) (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)